# Нужна ли запятая при двойном пожелании?

Tags: пунктуация

Вопрос немного дурацкий, но все же не дает покоя: нужна ли запятая в предложениях типа **"Спасибо(,) и удачи!", "До свидания(,) и всего хорошего!", "Спасибо(,) и хорошего дня!"?**

Пользуясь случаем, заодно хочу уточнить: верна ли постановка двоеточия в моей формулировке вопроса?
Заранее спасибо за ответы (и хорошего вам дня)!

Comment: Дарис, каждый вопрос лучше задавать отдельно. Вопрос о знаках препинания в вашей фразе  достоин отдельного обсуждения (не только о двоеточии, но и о конечном знаке вопроса).

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Попробую позже его сформулировать и уже в корректной форме задать!

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, это ССП. Следовательно, **запятая нужна**. Возможно, путаница возникла из-за предложений, в которых есть общий элемент и запятая не ставится именно из-за этого. Пример из Нацкорпуса:

*Всем спасибо и удачи!* (Гибадиева В. Китайский связной. Дневник Вероники Гибадиевой с ЧМ по водным видам спорта (2011).

Здесь "всем" - общий элемент для следующих за ним двух "мини-предложений"

Answer (score 2):

Если части сложносочинённого предложения являются побудительными, вопросительными или восклицательными предложениями, **запятая** между ними **не нужна**.

Comment: Действительно, зачем тут запятая? Правило привела Наталья.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что запятая здесь  нужна, так как это не однородные члены (союз И можно считать присоединительным): "Спасибо, и удачи!", "До свидания, и всего хорошего!", "Спасибо, и хорошего дня!"

Можно сравнить:

Действуйте, и удачи вам. Очень рада за Вас ― здоровья и удачи!

Еще раз ― с Новым годом, хорошего здоровья и удачи.

И вас с прошедшими, радости и удачи.

С Новым Годом! Счастья, здоровья и удачи!

Мы видим, что запятая (при наличии союза И) не ставится при перечислении только грамматически однородных членов. В остальных случаях ставится запятая/тире, или пожелание делится на два предложения.

Comment: Arina, пишете в ответе: "...запятая здесь не нужна", а в предложениях запятая имеется. Так КАК правильно?

Comment: Спасибо, ответ исправлен.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую дать Вам ответ.
Я думаю, что запятая не нужна, потому что [я Вас] *благодарю* и [одновременно желаю] *хорошего дня/удачи/всего хорошего*... Можно рассматривать их как однородные части, думаю...
But you'd better wait for a native speaker.

Comment: Прочитав ответы носителей языка я остаюсь при своем мнении, perdón. это эллиптические предложения: человек говорит спасибо и желает другому удачи. kак сказала Арина союз присоединительный: к одной части предложения присоединяется вторая часть. нет противопоставления, которое вызвало бы использование запятой.

Comment: "однородные части" вероя́тно неправильное выражение... скорее "равноправные части" (если в русском языке есть что-то такое) =)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы запятую во всех примерах использовал.
Не получаются части тут однородными. Об однородности можно уверенно говорить, если в случае, если изменяемые части речи имеют одинаковую форму (один падеж, одно лицо и число): "[Желаю тебе] доброго дня и хорошего настроения". А "спасибо" вообще членом предложения не бывает в обычном использовании, ну, может, в случае "От спасибо сыт не будешь".  Аналогично, "До свидания" не очень-то лезет в однородные, ну только если в пару со "здравствуйте".

Короче, я думаю, что здесь во всех случаях, при некоторой смысловой общности, составляющие выражены синтаксически разными членами предложения - по своей роли. А в этом случае правильно говорить не об однородности членов, но об ССП.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы (всем в этом треде)! Тоже больше склоняюсь к варианту, при котором запятая нужна, т. к. члены предложения неоднородные. :)